# Get all the file's version inside a folder

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I am trying to get the file version of all the files inside a folder which I managed to do (but not in a good way) but now I want to stick the folder name along with the version so I would know which version is for which folder.
I am not very good in command line and only use it for some small tasks whenever I need it so my apology in advance..
Here is what I have done:

`For /d %%a in (C:\high\low\*) Do (For /d %%* in (%%a) Do wmic datafile where name="%%~da\\high\\low\\%%~nx*\\bin\\Services.dll" get Version /value)`
and I get output as:

> `Version=2.2.0.1 Version=2.2.0.4 Version=2.2.0.4....Version=2.2.0.4

there are 20 folders under `C:\high\low` and I want to go into the bin directory of each sub folder so I can see which folder has been upgraded and which one is not.

**Edit**
There are more than 20 folders and structure is like this:
`C:\high\low\office.Services.Bolton\bin\Services.dll

C:\high\low\office.Services.Slough\bin\Services.dll

C:\high\low\office.Services.Hull\bin\Services.dll

.

.

.

C:\high\low\office.Services.Cosham\bin\Services.dll`
I want to check the version number of Services.dll and need the output as:
`Bolton - 2.2.0.1

Slough - 2.3.0.1

Hull - 2.5.0.1

.

.

.

Cosham - 2.0.0.0`

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of stacking `for /d` you could do a `dir /b/s` to find all Services.dll and parse the nasty (cr,cr,lf) output of wmic with a `for /f`:

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
For /F "tokens=*" %%A in (
  'Dir /B/S C:\high\low\Services.dll ^|findstr /i "bin\\Services.dll$"'
) Do (
  Set "DLL=%%~fA"
  Set "DLL=!DLL:\=\\!"
  For /F "tokens=1* delims==" %%B in (
    'wmic datafile where name^="!DLL!" get Version /value^|findstr Version'
  ) Do For /f "delims=" %%D in ("%%C") Do Echo Version: %%D   %%~fA
)
```

- The first For /f parses the output of the commamd inside the `''` iterating through each line passed in %%A (I prefer upper case variables to better distinguish between lower case`~` modifiers.
- Since `Dir` will allow wildcards only in the last element I can't do a `Dir /B/S C:\high\low\*\bin\Services.dll`
- To ashure I get only Services.dll in a bin folder I pipe dir output to `findstr /i "bin\\Services.dll$` (findstr uses by default a limited RegEx so the `\` has to be escaped with another one, the `$` anchors the expression at the end of the line).
- The wmic command needs the backslashes in the path also escaped what is possible with string substitution (works only with normal variables)
- In a (code block) we need delayed expansion to get actual values for variables changed in the code block, so `!` instead of `%` for framing the variable names
- The 2nd For /f parses wmic output splitting at the equal sign, assigning content to var %%C
- **EDIT** added another for /f to [remove the wmic cr](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4266)

Comment: Many thanks for the explanation however, I am getting error as `C:\\high\\low\\office.Services\\bin\\Services.dll - Invalid alias verb` **I have edited the question** for better understanding as I may have missed bits in that.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to escape the equal sign in the wmic command, changed above.

Comment: thanks, just few silly questions -  What does `"` do before `bin\\Services.dll$'`, why output does not change if its `Dir /B/S C:\high\low\Services.dll` or `Dir /B/S C:\high\low` and if I change `Do Echo Version: %%D  %%~fA` to `Do Echo Version: %%D   %%~nA` why I only get partial name as `office.Services` instead of something like `office.Services.Bolton`

Comment: The counterpart was missing, if there aren't characters which would be interpreted by the cmd interpreter quoting isn't necessary. (or multiple search strings delimited with a space)